# On my Raspberry Pi Pico - I need to read an SD-Card in 4bit SD mode with a GPIO in Python

Tags: python, gpio, sd-card

I need some help with my Raspberry Pi Pico using Python.
I want to read from an SD-Card in SD mode which is 4 bits wide.
My project is to read an AVI file from an SD-Card and display it on a small LED panel.

Can someone please help me with the bit of code that will interface between the GPIO and my python code.

I have found some GPIO code online here:
https://circuitcellar.com/resources/quickbits/rp2040-programmable-io/

I am new to Python and also GPIO coding - I don't know how to interface with the PIO code - so I don't know if it's the right code or if it works.

Comment: I believe it's **impossible** task to fulfill. Why? Because SD card 4-bit mode assumes you have the real SDHCI behind it, it's not easy to implement it via GPIOs in software (and if you can do that, it won't fit into small devices like yours).

Comment: well, in case anyone cares - it's possible. I got it working with a nice library from here:
https://github.com/carlk3/no-OS-FatFS-SD-SPI-RPi-Pico/tree/sdio
although it needed some changes to do SDIO instead of SPI.
It uses PIO to communicate with the card.